# how to remove the whitespace around images in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

So I want to remove the extra spaces highlighted in red ink shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Kwo.png

When I remove the top images the table width becomes correct: 800px

but what I wanted is this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPsz2.jpg

Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Adventure</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="STYLE04.css">
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:800px; height:600px" >
    <tr>
    <td colspan=3><img src="N13BANNER.PNG"></td>
    <td><img src="N13LOGO.PNG"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:176px"><img src="N13BUTTON1.PNG"></td>
    <td width=176><img src="N13IMG5.jpg"></td>
    <td colspan=2 rowspan=6><img src="DUNE204.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=176><img src="N13BUTTON2.PNG"></td>
    <td width=176><img src="N13IMG1.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=176><img src="N13BUTTON3.PNG"></td>
    <td width=176><img src="N13IMG4.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=176><img src="N13BUTTON4.PNG"></td>
    <td width=176><img src="N13IMG9.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width=176><a href="mailto:xahc@cie.org.uk?Subject=Adventure%20Me%20Up..."><img src="N13BUTTON5.PNG"></a></td>
    <td width=176><a href="mailto:xahc@cie.org.uk?Subject=Adventure%20Me%20Up..."><img src="N13IMG6.jpg"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2><h1>Webpage last edited by asdf</h1></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really consider not using the table element for layout. Do you really need that?

Answer (score 1):

Code sample, with an update of your table layout without the images.

Is this how you want? ... then your images is to big, and pushes the cells too wide.

```css
table {
  width: 800px;
}
td {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 20%;
  height: 85px;
}
tr:last-child td {
  height: 40px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan=3 rowspan=6></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><a href="mailto:xahc@cie.org.uk?Subject=Adventure%20Me%20Up...">mail</a></td>
    <td><a href="mailto:xahc@cie.org.uk?Subject=Adventure%20Me%20Up...">mail</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>Webpage last edited by asdf</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @asdftestonly I did an update, please reply and also post your css.